# Swift2 treats BOOL function (objc code) with NSError parameter as Void function

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift2

Weird thing happened when I convert my Swift 1 project to Swift 2, namely Swift2 treats a return type BOOL function with NSError as a return type Void function.

For example, my code uses XMPPFramework, where there is a function defined as following:

```
- (BOOL)authenticateWithPassword:(NSString *)password error:(NSError **)errPtr;
```

I used to have a piece of code which does this:

```
if (xmppStream!.authenticateWithPassword(password)) {
    println("authenticated");
}
```

now it has been updated to follow Swift 2 syntax:

```
do {
    if let result = try xmppStream!.authenticateWithPassword(password) {
        print("authenticate");
    }
} catch _ {}
```

For some reason swift 2 treats authenticateWithPassword as a void type function, thus the code above failed to pass compilation.

Just wondering if anyone has ran into the same situation and what was the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was my solution:

```
do {
    try xmppStream!.authenticateWithPassword(password)
    print("authenticate");
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That certainly passed the compilation, and I did this so my app could run again, just wondering how the type shifted. Also, I have other functions suffering from the same situation, some of the return values are essential to my logic.

Comment: I think that swift2.0 wants forced us to use `do-catch` around the code that can throw errors. If there are any errors, the `do statement` will stop executing, so the return value is not necessary. Also, you can separate your logic into three separate block: `do` 、`catch` and `defer`.

Comment: Thanks @Bannings, I'll go ahead and apply this to all of my code.